# Listing List Item Attributes with JQuery on Sharepoint, linking to more JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, attributes

So my company has a Sharepoint 2007 server running, and I have been tasked with setting up a Project Management space through that service. My goal is this- to be able to generate PDFs, client-side, containing information from whatever List Item the user chooses.

What I have accomplished so far is determining that I can use a Shared Content Editor Web Part on the Default page, I can include JS in this web part, and that this JS can pull up List Item Titles using JQuery. The code I'm using is shown below (borrowed from an online article)-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-

1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var soapEnv =
            "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
                <soapenv:Body> \
                     <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                        <listName>Tasks</listName> \
                        <viewFields> \
                            <ViewFields> \
                               <FieldRef Name='Status' /> \
                           </ViewFields> \
                        </viewFields> \
                    </GetListItems> \
                </soapenv:Body> \
            </soapenv:Envelope>";

        $.ajax({
            url: "_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            complete: processResult,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });
    });

    function processResult(xData, status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
            var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
            $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
        });
    }
</script>

<ul id="tasksUL"/>
```

Problem 1 - Inside the SOAP Envelope call, I tried changing the "FieldRef Name" value to 'Status' but found that this does nothing (if you're asking yourself about now if I have any JS experience, the answer is pretty much No). Down in the ***processResult*** method, I tried changing the attribute from "ows_Title" to "ows_Status" or "Status" to no avail. I just get back "undefined" for each List Item.

Problem 2 - I want the user to be able to select a List Item and generate a PDF summary of the data. I know about Marak's PDF.JS library, but I'm not sure how to combine the two (in other words, I'm not sure how to either call the JS from within each List Item or have a separate list with the Item names that calls the JS).

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Actually, 'ows_Status' did work, I must've just typed it wrong while editing the JS. This helped- alert(xData.responseText);

Still need to figure out the linking, though...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at my SPServices jQuery library to make it easier on yourself. I've done all of the SOAP work for you. http://SPServices.codeplex.com